# Removing water/moisture from car exhaust

Tags: water, distillation, filtering

I know that car exhaust is almost entirely nitrogen, water and carbon dioxide. How would I go about removing the water? Would I have to condense it off? Any devices already exist for doing so?

Comment: how much of the water do you want to remove/how dry do you want the exhaust to be?

Comment: Keeping costs reasonable, as dry as possible. Ideally no water content at all but I gather that'll be pretty difficult and expensive. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Certainly devices exist to remove water vapour from gas streams. Many labs pass their nitrogen stream through a conc. sulfuric acid bubbler to ensure it is dry. Solid absorbents such as silica gel or Drierite can also be used. The question is what volume of exhaust gas do you want to dry? These absorbents need to be changed frequently to maintain the dryness of the gas stream. If you want to keep a lot of exhaust dry you'll need a lot of drying agent.